# How can I fight off the sharks in the dhow?

Tags: skull-and-bones

After the introductionary tutorial with the big battle, you are given control of a dhow. The area has many sharks that will attack your ship when you get too close. They will damage the hull and might eventually even sink the ship.

How can I fight off the sharks in the early part of the game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a spear to attack the sharks, which is not available until you complete the first few quests.

After you obtain the spear you can kill the sharks in 4-5 hits and loot the meat and other resources by approaching the corpse. The schools of fish can be harvested in the same way.